# UITextView memory leak in ios6?

Tags: ios

I use iPhone 6 simulator in Xcode. After I add a simple UITextView in my view, I type some word in it. But I found some errors in console:

```
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Oct 19 10:07:14 localhost textViewTest[1438] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

And when I watch the memory use ,it increase very fast.But when I use iphone5 or iphone4.3 Simulator it will not appear.

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
    [textView release];

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval =5.0 ;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(handleMaxShowTimer:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

}
- (double)availableMemory
{
    vm_statistics_data_t vmStats;
    mach_msg_type_number_t infoCount = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;
    kern_return_t kernReturn = host_statistics(mach_host_self(),HOST_VM_INFO,(host_info_t)&vmStats,&infoCount);
    if(kernReturn != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        return NSNotFound;
    }
    return ((vm_page_size * vmStats.free_count) / 1024.0) / 1024.0;
}

- (double)usedMemory
{
    task_basic_info_data_t taskInfo;
    mach_msg_type_number_t infoCount = TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;
    kern_return_t kernReturn = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                     TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)&taskInfo, &infoCount);
    if(kernReturn != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return NSNotFound;
    }
    return taskInfo.resident_size / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
}

-(void)handleMaxShowTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    NSLog(@" use memory  %f  remain memory  %f",[self usedMemory],[self availableMemory]);

}
@end
```

Comment: I would hope that you are releasing the ref you explicitly own in the function that's calling all that drawing code, otherwise it would be leaking like crazy.  Show us that.

Comment: Also, this view controller will never be released because the repeating timer will retain it, and you lost the reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your memory usage most likely isn't "increasing like crazy", you just happen to be looking at the total number of bytes allocated in instruments, which is meant to steadily increase.  Use the actual leaks tool and it will even tell you the exact line of code the leaks occur at, and how much one particular function is contributing to the overall leakage.

As for the CG... Errors, drawing code needs to be done in a `-drawRect:` override, which is the only place you can get a stable non-NULL context to draw into.

Comment: the only place you can get a stable non-NULL context to draw into *from the system*

Comment: @borrrden If I should ever hope to be so literal... You're absolutely correct, though, I hope you weren't implying that one can retrieve a valid context behind Core Graphic's back...?

Comment: What I meant is that it is perfectly fine to create your own context, (although it won't be drawn to the screen) :).  Also, I don't think OP is using Instruments.  He may not even have any draw code, as he said it happens when he types text into a text view.

Comment: Did you mean it actually not a problem？

Comment: Depending on where you look, and what you look at, yes.